# How to query to display pairing field in MySQL ( for Hierarchical data )

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with the following data in MySQL:

```
id       lft       rgt
a          1        0
a          0        1
a          2        0
a          0        2
a          3        0  
b          1        0
b          0        1
b          2        0
```

how do I get it into the following format to insert in new table (pair between lft and rgt)

```
id         lft     rgt
a          1       1   
a          2       2
b          1       1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood you question correctly, then the below code will help.

I tested with the data you supplied with Mysql and got the result you wanted. The mysql statement is:

```
SELECT a.id,a.lft,b.rgt from test a INNER JOIN test b ON a.lft=b.rgt and (a.lft>0) GROUP BY a.lft,a.id order by a.id
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted. The screen shot of the output i received is as below

[image]

Comment: i try but i can't :( i have less than 15 reputation